# Why does the bottle create vacuum inside if left closed?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, everyday-life, vacuum, gas

I'm not 100% it's correct but it has happened to me a lot of times, I always close down a bottle normally with not too much tightness, with no liquid inside, and after a day it always is so hard to open the lid up. I assume that somehow, after a day left closed down, it *somehow* creates a little more of vacuum inside the bottle, so that would explain the tightness of the bottle after a day or so.

Could that be true by any chance? If so, why would that happen?

Comment: May be other reasons (not just relative vacuum) as well. For example, if lid is wet and bottle liquid has sugar inside, then after some time water can evaporate leaving sugar in crystal form which can act as a "glue" between the lid and the bottle.

Comment: Or if, for instance, the bottle was warm before closing and then cools down. My Hydroflask for coffee does that, becoming very hard to open in the evening unless I leave it unscrewed to vent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to agree with the comment from Agnius Vasiliauskas above. However, if what you experienced is really happening due to a decline in the pressure within the bottle, then I can outline a rough argument as to how that could happen.

By an abuse of the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas), we can say that (symbols have usual meaning)
$$ P_{\rm inside} = \frac{nRT}{V}.$$

Now let us assume that your bottle is very stiff so that even if somehow the inside pressure falls down, still its volume $V$ does not change. In addition, $n$ should remain constant in a sealed bottle. Then, in that case
$$ P_{\rm inside} \propto T.$$

So **if the outside temperature falls** down and you let the bottle's temperature to come in equilibrium with the outside temperature (say via conductive or radiative process), then $P_{\rm inside}$ will also decrease. **In this way, we can create a situation where $P_{\rm inside} < P_{\rm outside}$**.

Comment: so, if we wanted to free it up a little bit, could we make our lifes easier to open it by heating it up a little bit?

Comment: I guess, yes. Maybe you can try and give also me an update :)